# when i want to test my app with a real device the app doesnt start

Tags: java, android, testing, android-emulator

I've been trying to test my app where I'm implementing a G+ sign in and when I run it in the emulator with Android Studio the app runs but says that I need to update Google Play Services.

I've been struggling to do that so I thought that I would just test it on a real device but when I do the app doesn't start/run. When I go to settings and apps on device I can see that the app is installed but it doesn't show up in the app drawer or anywhere else.

I get this exception under my run tab in the bottom left corner:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.madchallenge2016edwindaniel.upbirdwatchers/.LoginActivity } from null (pid=20620, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10154
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1948)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:463)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:276)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
<intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
</application>
```

Here is the code of my launch activity:

```
package com.madchallenge2016edwindaniel.upbirdwatchers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private SignInButton mSignInButton;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        //Background
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.login_background);

        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new     GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    SignInButton mSignInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    signIn();
                    break;
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
}

//Start sign in
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }


}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

    if (result.isSuccess()) {



    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        // updateUI(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void setmSignInButton(SignInButton mSignInButton) {
    this.mSignInButton = mSignInButton;
}
}
```

After editing my manifest file according to the answer I got, my app now runs.
This is what my updated manifest file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

Comment: and of course you did tried all solution which can be found for *not exported from uid* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed Intent filter in android manifest

Please replace your manifest with below code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
</application>
```

Intent filters show when to launch this activity. usually you will have one activity with intent filter that is to show that it is first activity when application is launched.

Comment: i still get the same result even after adding intent filter

Comment: i have add android:exported="true" in activity

Comment: my launch activity is the loginActivity so must i put the intent filter there?

Comment: make sure you r giving intent filter to correct activity

Comment: yes you should put intent filter in LoginActivity not in MainActivity

Comment: but why does the app run on the emulator if the intent filter isnt there?

Comment: intentfilter is  required for the first activity in your application ... not able understand ur scenario(emulator)

Comment: what i meant was when i run the app in emulator it works but when i run on real device it doesnt work

Comment: man i must be slow or something but after going through your answer many times i was able to understand and fix my mistake thank you very much